# Socket.io application works locally but not on Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, socket.io

I am creating a React application and a Node server that are supposed to communicate with each other through sockets, using socket.io.  When I have everything connected on my local computer, I do not run into any issues.  However, when I use my deployed server, my React application gets the following error in the console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://{URL TO MY HEROKU SERVER}/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NNjgExO' 
from origin '{URL FOR MY HEROKU REACT APP}' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value '48506'.
```

I ran into a similar issue locally when putting the application together, and learned that I needed to use cors within my server to allow connections.  When I did that on my local machine, it worked.  However, now that I have it deployed, I am getting this type of error again.  I know there is some kind of cors settings for this I need to change, but I really don't know what needs to be changed.
Here is the server code:

```
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server, {
  cors: {
    allRoutes: true,
    origin: PORT,
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    allowedHeaders: ["my-custom-header"],
    credentials: true,
  },
});
```

And here is the React app code for connecting:

```
socket = io(ENDPOINT, {
      withCredentials: true,
      extraHeaders: {
        "my-custom-header": "abcd",
      },
    });
```

EDNPOINT refers either to my localhost server or the url for the deployed server, depending on the environment I am working in.  Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure out the cors settings with trial and error.  For anyone interested, here are the settings below that work for me:

Server:

```
const cors = require("cors");
const socketio = require("socket.io");

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = socketio(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    allowedHeaders: ["content-type"],
  },
});
```

Client:

```
socket = io(ENDPOINT);
```